# NSLocalizedString with superscript

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nslocalizedstring, superscript

How would you add superscript inside an NSLocalized string?

I'm trying to write a superscript 2, if I do it like this, it works:

```
[title setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CO\u00B2 %@",NSLocalizedString(@"c04View01_title", @"Title for current page")]];
```

But if I add the superscript to the localized string, it doesn't work, it just interprets that as 5 characters:

```
"c04View01_title" = "CO\u00B2 PROGRAMMERS";

[title setText:NSLocalizedString(@"c04View01_title", @"Title for current page")]];
```

The problem happens, when the string with the superscript is between strings, so I need to split the string in two parts, but in some languages the superscripted string ends up at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Just use the character directly in your strings file, don't bother backslash-encoding it. Or try an upper-case 'U' which Apple's documentation uses.

Comment: Well... that... was an easy fix. Upper-case U works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an upper-case 'U' for the backslash-escape, as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-SW13):

```
"c04View01_title" = "CO\U00B2 PROGRAMMERS";
```

You can also just put the character directly in the strings file, un-escaped. There is no need to backslash-encode most characters.